# How to set which segment in segmented controller is selected

Tags: swift

I have 3 segments in a segmented controller.  They act as sort by buttons, effecting the order of an array displayed inside a tableview in another view controller.  The segmented controller and table view are in separate scenes.

The 3 segments are distance, rating and A-Z in that order.  I will select A-Z, which will order them alphabetically when I return to the tableview.  But, if I was to return to the scene with the segmented controller, leaving the scene where the tableview is, the distance segment will be highlighted.  Nevertheless, they are still sorted A-Z.

How do I keep the segment that I originally tapped highlighted rather than it always being the first segment?

Answer (score 0):

Not quit sure about your question.

But thats how you save and select a index of a UISegmentControl

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

var selectedIndex = 0

// Save
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedIndex
}

// Load and Select
@IBAction func segmentControlValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    selectedIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```